# Appscript to perform pivot operation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula

I would like to perform pivot operation on gsheet data through Appscript.

Example Data:

[image]

Comment: Why not just use query?

Comment: If you really want to use Google Apps Script, start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use a [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) formula:

```
=query($A$1:$E$7,"Select A,B,C,Sum(E)  Group By A,B,C Order By B Label Sum(E) 'Marks' ")
```

[image: example]

---

If you really want to use pivot tables and Google Apps Script then please have a look at the [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets#create_a_pivot_table). There are a couple of examples which are quite straightforward.